# Filling in the pandas dataframe with array values matching index and headers

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have a an empty dataframe say:

```
| (index)  | prevelance   |frequency   |
| -------- | -------------|------------|
| 12       | NaN          |NaN         |
| 13       | NaN          |NaN         |
| 14       | NaN          |NaN         |
```

and an array:

num -- criteria -- count

12. prevalence 3

    frequency  4
13. prevelance 5

    frequency  2
14. prevelance 6

    frequency 7

(grouped by num)

I want to fill in the Dataframe with the prevalence and frequency values of the array, where the array header num - matches data-frame index

helping hands appreciated.

Comment: We would need to see some sample data, and your code

Comment: Why would you do this? You'll have the same results is you just load the array into pandas directly.